# How to get specific substring with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract and return the substring from a string which looks like this:

```
Array ( [query] => Array ( [normalized] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [from] => lion [to] => Lion ) ) [pages] => Array ( [36896] => Array ( [pageid] => 36896 [ns] => 0 [title] => Lion [extract] => The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the four big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. With some males exceeding 250 kg (550 lb) in weight, it is the second-largest living cat after the tiger. ) ) ) )
```

The specific substring I need is always located between **[extract] =>** and **))))**. I'm pretty bad at regex, and would appreciate any help!

I tried

```
preg_match('/\[extract\] =>(.*?)\)\)\)\)', $c,$hits);
```

and some other stuff, but nothing worked...

EDIT:
Here's the full code I'm using:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=txt&exsentences=2&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&iwurl=&titles=lion';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestScript"); // required by wikipedia.org server; use YOUR user agent with YOUR contact information. (otherwise your IP might get blocked)
$c = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('^.*\[extract\].?\=\>.?(.*).?\).?\).?\).?\)$', $c,$hits); 

print_r ($hits);
```

Comment: So bad that you didn't even try anything. At least a language, I don't think regex is needed for this, `indexOf` and `substring` will do the trick.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work, and I figured it was probably to horrible to put on the screen :-). But I've edited the question.

Comment: It may be ugly but it will look better than nothing. Try something like `data.substring(data.indexOf("[extract] =>")+"[extract] =>".length(), data.length()-8);` Your regex seems to be failing because of spaces, if you add `\s` between parentheses it'll work.

Comment: @JavierDiaz I'm using php.

Comment: you didn't write it at the very first time but you can use that as example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well considering  that in both of your examples you are missing pattern delimiters, indeed it will not work as expected. Also you need to to match multiple accounts of *whitespace* to get back your desired result.

```
preg_match('/\[extract\]\s*=>\s*(.*?)(?:\s*\)){4}/i', $c, $hits); 
echo $hits[1];
```

Output

```
The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the four big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. With some males exceeding 250 kg (550 lb) in weight, it is the second-largest living cat after the tiger.
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/rW7vL5)

- Regular expression:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

just because it's really funny how you want to solve this, here is regex (edited so there can be whitespace or not between ) ):

```
^.*\[extract\].?\=\>.?(.*).?\).?\).?\).?\)$
```

but you should definitelly use array functions to get to [extract] field and you will get it's content which is the part you want

tested here: http://regex101.com/r/qO5vO0

for php:

```
preg_match('/.*?\[extract\]\s\=\>\s(.*?)\s\)\s\)\s\)\s\)/i', $c, $hits);

echo $hits[1]; //outputs captured string
```

Comment: I tried using [extract] but it didn't work. I think the response I'm getting is a simple string, not an array, although it looks like one...

Comment: what is giving you this output ? the regex should work (at least on you example), did you try it ?

Comment: I just tried the following but it didn't work: preg_match('^.*\[extract\].?\=\>.?(.*).?\).?\).?\).?\)$', $c,$hits);

print_r ($hits);

Comment: preg_match('/.*[extract].?\=\>.?(.*).?).?).?).?)/', $c,$hits); print_r ($hits); ?

Comment: ahh, sure it doesn't return, I've just copy-pasted your string and it's wrong, you have to preserve backslashes like in code above

Comment: It's still not working, although it should. I've edited my question and included the full code I'm using...

Comment: and what about php code that I've added to my answer ? I've tested it with the string you gave us, it's working for me ..

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use regex (and as @JavierDiaz says it seems like overkill) then you could use this:

```
\[extract\](.*?)\)\s\)\s\)\s\)
```

Your example appears to have a space between each closing parenthesis at the end of the string - I'm not sure if that's intentional or not. If not, remove the `\s` bits.

The basic explanation is this:

```
\[         A literal '['
extract    A literal string
\]         A literal ']'
(          Start of capturing group
.*?        Any characters, any number of repetitions but as few as possible (non-greedy)
)          End of capturing group
\)         A literal ')'
\s         Any whitespace
\)         A literal ')'
\s         Any whitespace
\)         A literal ')'
\s         Any whitespace
\)         A literal ')'
```

you can try it out using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) or any other free RegEx editor (lots of them about).

EDIT: I knocked this up before an edit to the OP's question which adds that the `=>` should not be included. Changing the start to `\[extract\].+?\s(.*?)` would do the trick, but this has been covered much better by [Michael Perrenoud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494938/60602) in another answer.

Comment: You may want to use {4} instead of that ugly regex, just a tip.

Comment: Yes you could, but I wanted to demonstrate an expanded version in case it is not guaranteed that the end of the string will always be a single whitespace followed by a closing parenthesis four times as it's not entirely clear from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick. You're looking for the string `extract` first, then you want to get to the start of the text with `.+=>\s`, then you'll grab all the text `(.*?)` in a *non-greedy* fashion until you find the end of the string with `\s\)\s\)\s\)\s\)`:

```
extract.+=>\s(.*?)\s\)\s\)\s\)\s\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-DT4z2AzbsUyeQMt)

---

As stated by Javier in Steve's post, you could also do this:

```
extract.+=>\s(.*?)(?:\s\)){4}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xjIF9RRQFaSinfp-)

Comment: +1 just for Debuggex - not seen that before, will make use of it!

Comment: @StevePettifer: thanks! And I meant to give you a +1 as that's absolutely a 100% right answer.